# Derivation of a formula that connects distance moved by the sphere and the flow rate of water

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I am a grade 12 student conducting a physics experiment on Bernoulli's principle and the coanda effect. In the experiment set-up shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/Fs3kyOh), a sphere made of Styrofoam is suspended in the air next to the tap. When the tap is turned on, the sphere gets 'attracted' towards the jet stream and the water starts to flow along the curvature of the sphere. For my experiment, I am trying to derive a formula that connects the flow rate of water and the distance moved by the sphere i.e., How does the varying flow rate of water affect the distance moved by the sphere. I am not even sure how I can draw a free body diagram for this experiment. Can someone please help me with this derivation of the formula that connects these 2 variables please. I am hoping to obtain a linear equation at the end. It is alright if the derivation requires math that is much more complicated than high school math as we are expected to go way beyond our syllabus.

Comment: Please mention what you've tried, where you are stuck, etc. Homework like questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @StutiGupta Hi, sorry for being vague. This is not a homework question. This is the experiment I chose to write a research paper on. We are required to write a 4000 word essay using this experiment including the background information, analysis of data, evaluation of data etc. What I am trying to do is to derive a formula that connects flowrate of water and distance moved by the sphere which enables me to check the accuracy of the results in the essay. I will make another post explaining what I have done so far and what exactly I need help with.

Comment: how many times are you asking the same question? You and/or some of your friend/collegue https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/798158/derivation-of-an-equation-that-links-flow-rate-of-water-and-distance-moved-by-th

Comment: @basics sorry, I made a separate post because @/Stuti Gupta said I have not provided enough details. Both accounts are mine, I will remove this post.

Comment: You're not supposed to make a separate post for that... Use the Edit option add on things to this one.

Comment: @StutiGupta Got it

Comment: @basics Hi I tried to read through the document (https://gitlab.com/davideMontagnani/fluidmechanics-ita/-/blob/master/template/mainEseFull.pdf?ref_type=heads) and figure out a way to derive my formula but I am really struggling:( Can you please guide me through it.

Comment: @basics I tried to do a sample calculation on one of my data sets using the formula given in that document and I keep getting really small values of R(x) and R(y). Not sure why this is happening:(

Comment: @basics Please help me, I cannot write a lot in my research paper if I do not have a proper equation:(

Answer (score 0):

The attraction of the sphere towards the right(in the given pic) is due to the thrust force induced in the sphere due to the water exiting the contact from the surface of the sphere.

doing this would be very much prone to error in real world circumstances as the forces involved are pretty small and the light ball is prone to error due to stuff like wind and small convection currents due to unequal pressure and heat distribution that might be prevalent in the room.

Ideally, the thrust force that pushes the ball towards the stream would be $F_{Tx} = v_x\cdot \frac{dm}{dt}$ where $\frac{dm}{dt}$ is the mass flow rate in the x direction. I am considering only the x direction because that would be the force that is pulling the sphere towards the waterflow(x direction is tangential at the moment).

You would also have to consider stuff like viscosity and air resistance and the equation that you will end up getting would be far from a linear one.

Comment: Hi, how do I relate it to the distance moved by the sphere? Also, is it possible for me to calculate the force being applied by water using rotational equilibrium (as you can see in the image the sphere is slightly rotated before coming to a stop). 

Can you please guide me through the derivation of the formula that considers viscosity and air resistance as well. It's alright if I do not end up with a linear equation as long as the equation I derive fits my data well.